# jQuery flexslider: how to change a slide while running and avoid side effects

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm using flexslider to display a series of photos. Over Ajax, I get new slide sets at regular intervals, every 30 seconds. Updating the slide set inside flexslider goes more or less OK, using `addSlide()` and `removeSlide()`, but comes with side effects.

1) The `currentSlide` variable in flexslider advances beyond the last slide. This results in empty slides display, as these slides are non existent. So, I've added some repair code to loop around the `currentSlide`pointer:

```
current = slider.currentSlide;
...slider.addSlide(...);
...slider.removeSlide(...);
slider.currentSlide = current < slider.count ? current : slider.count - 1;
```

This remedies the problem, but is pretty ugly.

2) The next challenge is, that during slide updates the flexslider administration gets messed up. This results in change of slide order (I can live with that), unregular number of slides, reversal of slide direction, and empty slides being displayed. 
As a test, I've triggered my code on an 'after' event, using

```
after : function(slider) {updateImages(slider)}
```

to workaround potential race conditions, but alas, this did not improve the situation.

3) I've tried to stop and start the flexslider show during the update, using `slider.flexslider("pause")` and `slider.flexslider("start")` methods. Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

I get the impression I'm doing something utterly wrong and forgetting something very essential. Has someone a clue?